# Remove the ImageView height if no image to set

Tags: android, android-layout

Sometimes I have an image to set in an ImageView, sometimes not.
The problem is when I have no image, I'd like to remove the blank space added by the ImageView.

```
if(post.getImageUrl()!=null || !post.getImageUrl().equals("")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
        }
        else{
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

my xml

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

But it is not working, the blank space is still there.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Invert your logic.

Set the visibility to GONE in the XML

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

In the Picasso condition for loading the image, set it VISIBLE, and remove the else

```
Picasso imgLoader = Picasso.with(context);
String imgUrl = post.getImageUrl();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(imgUrl)) {
    holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgLoader.load(imgUrl).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

---

Alternatively, load a default, placeholder image

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(post.getImageUrl())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // A default image
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // An error image
    .into(holder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Solution**

set the visibilty To Gone in your ImageView  xml

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

and make it visible in your code Inside if block

```
if(post.getImageUrl()!=null || !post.getImageUrl().equals("")) {


holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                        Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
                    }


         <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Answers is to set height of ImageView as 0 is :

```
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(null);
```